# Comparing numbers in JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have number property in JSON schema

`"years": {"type": "number", "pattern": "^([0-9]|10)$"}`

I want to match this number in a condition where I need to check whether number is less than 3, is there a way to do it ? I tried

`"if": {"properties": {"years": {"anyOf": [0,1,2]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `exclusiveMaximum`. see https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#range

note that you may want `minimum: 0` to exclude negative numbers.
you may also want `type: integer` instead of `type: number` if you don't want to include fractional numbers.

`pattern` is incorrect as it applies to strings, not numbers.
`anyOf` takes a schema, not values, but you could use `enum: [0, 1, 2]` if those are the only allowed values.